# Rest API SOQL Query Malformed

Tags: soql, rest-api

I'm trying this **SOQL** query in the **REST** Explorer:

```
/services/data/v39.0/query/?q=SELECT+AssigneeId+PermissionSet.Id+Assignee.Name+PermissionSet.Name+PermissionSet.Label+FROM+PermissionSetAssignment+WHERE+PermissionSet.Id=[AN ID]
```

`[AN ID]` is formed like `'0000'`

It's saying that it's malformed at `Assignee.Name`.

I don't know where I'm going wrong with this query as it works in the developer console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fields must be comma delimited. If you were to run the query listed in your URL in the `Developer Console`, it would translate to:

```
SELECT AssigneeId PermissionSet.Id Assignee.Name PermissionSet.Name PermissionSet.Label
FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Id='0000'
```

Of course this query will not work. The properly delimited query would be:

```
SELECT AssigneeId, PermissionSet.Id, Assignee.Name, PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.Label
FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSet.Id='0000'
```

And the properly formed URL would be:

```
q=SELECT+AssigneeId,PermissionSet.Id,Assignee.Name,PermissionSet.Name,PermissionSet.Label+FROM+PermissionSetAssignment+WHERE+PermissionSet.Id='0000'
```

---

Note that the `SOQL Developer Guide` makes this point clear in **[SOQL SELECT Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm)** (emphasis mine):

> **Syntax**
>   `fieldList`*`subquery`*
>
> **Description**
>   Specifies a list of one or more fields, **separated by commas**, that you want to retrieve from the specified object. The bold elements in the following examples are fieldlists:
>
> ```
> SELECT Id, Name, BillingCity FROM Account
> SELECT count() FROM Contact
> SELECT Contact.Firstname, Contact.Account.Name FROM Contact
> ```
>
> You must specify valid field names and must have read-level permissions to each specified field. The fieldList defines the ordering of fields in the query results.
>
> `fieldList` can include a subquery if the query traverses a relationship. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT Account.Name, (SELECT Contact.LastName FROM Account.Contacts)
> FROM Account
> ```
>
> The `fieldlist` can also be an aggregate function, such as `COUNT()` and `COUNT(fieldName)`, or be wrapped in Translating Results.

Comment: Worked! I wish the documentation on the Salesforce would say that.

Comment: @akcorp2003 Ah, but it does. See my updated answer for citation there.

Comment: Whoops. I meant the documentation for REST API. It's obvious that a SOQL statement has commas but the REST API documentation only shows a sample query with only 1 selected field. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm